# mod_rewrite, redirect and set a cookie, preventing redirection loop

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, cookies

i´m stuck here now for hours... any help will be appreciated!

**What I need to do:**

There is a application where in need to "protect". This means that I need to show a "disclaimer" page, which is not part of the protected application itself, but under the very same domain/server. This disclaimer page needs to be shown to every visitor every 8 hours.

**My concept:**

1. In Apache, on every request, check if there is a specific cookie "intercepted" present.
2. If there is a cookie, just process the requested url without any changes.
3. If there is no cookie, and the url is not catch.html, redirect to /catch.html?intercepted_url={requerst_uri_with_params}. in same step, set the cookie.
4. The browser will set the cookie, follow the redirection and load the catch.html (the cookie is present already), the user will see a disclaimer on this page.
5. On catch.html, using JavaScript, the cookie "intercepted" will be updated with a lifespan of 8 hours
6. On catch.html, using JavaScript, a link will be rendered, pointing to the intercepted url.
7. User will click the created link and issue an new request to the previously intercepted request
8. GOTO: 1

**What I´ve tried so far:**

***Apache Configuration:***

```
# Exclude the catch destination in order to prevent a redirect loop
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/catch.html
# Check if the cookie "intercepted" is missing
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !intercepted
# Redirect and append the original url as request parameter, preserving params, and setting the cookie
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /catch.html?intercepted_url=$1 [QSA,R=301,CO=intercepted:TRUE:%{HTTP_HOST}]
```

***Current Outcome:***

1. Opening http://local.example.com/foo/bar/baz.html?a=b&x=z&1=2 results i a redirection, as expected, OK
2. Retrying the first url should now pass, as the cookie is set, but no, im´m stuck on the disclaimer page :(

Any ideas how to fix this? Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the concept works as expected. the redirection is executed as described but the browser had cached the redirection as it was a permanent one (301). the solution was to use a temporarily redirection (302).

i've ended up to store also the intercepted url in the cookie in order to keep the url clean. but i did not managed to set the livetime of the cookie with the redirection. there seems to be no way to calculate it within the rewrite rule.
i have used some javascript to rewrite the cookie on the catch page.